# Uniformly continuous functions in terms of limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

In terms of limits, a function is continuous at a point $a$, if
$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$.
Now, what can we say about uniformly continuous functions in terms of limits?

Answer (score 5):

$f(x_n)-f(y_n) \to 0$ whenever $x_n-y_n \to 0$.

Comment: If your function is defined on  a metric space you can repalce $x_n-y_n \to 0$ by $d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$. Similar change when the range is another metric space.